# C++ Vector и его метод Push_back

Tags: c++, vector

Имеется некий код:

```
A a1;
A a2;
A a3;
std::vector<A> a;
std::cout << "Push back a1" << std::endl;
a.push_back(a1);
std::cout << "Push back a2" << std::endl;
a.push_back(a2);
std::cout << "Push back a3" << std::endl;
a.push_back(a3);
```

И разумеется класс А.

```
class A {
static int ACount;
private:

public:
A() {
    std::cout << "Constructor called. Objects = " << ++ACount << std::endl;
}
~A() {
    std::cout << "Destructor called. Objects = " << --ACount << std::endl;
}
A(const A &a) {
    std::cout << "Copy Constructor called. Objects = " << ++ACount << 
std::endl;
}
};
int A::ACount;
```

Вывод с консоли такой:

```
Constructor called. Objects = 1
Constructor called. Objects = 2
Constructor called. Objects = 3
Push back a1;
Copy constructor called. Objects = 4
Push back a2;
Copy constructor called. Objects = 5
Copy constructor called. Objects = 6
Destructor called. Objects = 5
Push back a3;
Copy constructor called. Objects = 6
Copy constructor called. Objects = 7
Copy constructor called. Objects = 8
Destructor called. Objects = 7
Destructor called. Objects = 6
Destructor called. Objects = 5
Destructor called. Objects = 4
Destructor called. Objects = 3
Destructor called. Objects = 2
Destructor called. Objects = 1
Destructor called. Objects = 0
```

Не могу понять почему при вызове метода Push_back(а2) вызывается 2 раза конструктор копирования, а при Push_back(а3) целых 3 раза. Пытаюсь создать некое подобие граф движка и создание\уничтожение такого числа объектов мне очень навредит. Как быть? Или стоит поискать некий иной контейнер?

Comment: Добавьте после     `std::vector<A> a;` вызов  `a.reserve(10);` и посмотрите результаты...

Answer (score 6):

Происходит переаллокация вектора при каждом `push_back`. Вы видите вызовы конструкторов копирования для копирования элементов со старого места на новое, а затем деструкцию элементов на старом месте.

Сделайте предварительное

```
a.reserve(100);
```

и "лишние" копирования и деструкции пропадут.

Comment: Большое спасибо. И ещё вопрос: Когда создается вектор 'std::vector<A> a' он резервирует память для одного элемента или нет? То есть переаллокация происходит каждый раз при вызове push_back() или только со второго раза?

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый: Это определятся реализацией. Стандарт языка не накладывает никаких требований на начальную capacity вектора. Запросите `capacity()` у своего вектора сразу после конструктора и посмотрите, что оно вернет. Скорее всего `0`.

Answer (score 0):

> Не могу понять почему при вызове метода Push_back(а2) вызывается 2 раза конструктор копирования, а при Push_back(а3) целых 3 раза

При увеличении размера вектора создается новый вектор, в него копируются все элементы старого и за**push**енный элемент, а затем все элементы старого уничтожаются.

Это связанно с тем, что вектор гарантирует последовательное непрерывное хранение элементов в памяти.

> Как быть?

Можно заранее зарезервировать достаточное количество элементов.

> Или стоит поискать некий иной контейнер?

Это зависит от того, что вам нужно от контейнера. Какие именно операции вы будете с ним делать.

У вектора поиск произвольного элемента идет за константное время, а добавление нового (если специально не резервировать пространство) - за O(N).
Также вектор можно передавать в функции как указатель на C-like массив.

У списка за константное время идет поиск, добавление и удаление первого и последнего элемента, а произвольного элемента - за O(N).

Comment: Не 'создается новый вектор', а 'выделяется новый кусок памяти'. И не 'при увеличении размера', а 'при увеличении емкости' (capacity).